# Postgres insert an array of an user-defined type with an array inside

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-types, composite-types

I created this type for length:

`CREATE TYPE length AS (value numeric, uom text );`

Then I created a type that is an array of length

`CREATE TYPE test_type AS (comp_height length[]);`

After this, I created a table with a column of type test_type array

`CREATE TABLE test_table (test_column test_type[]);`

Now I can not insert into this table. I have tried this way

```
insert into test_table (test_column)
values (
    ARRAY[
          ARRAY[(1,'m')::length,
                (20,'m')::length],
          ARRAY[(3,'m')::length,
                (40,'m')::length]
         ]::test_type
        );
```

but I get a cast error :(

`ERROR:  cannot cast type length[] to test_type`

I appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=452435d2548eb05155f5df431e2d50d3)

Your have to convert the `length[]` into a record using `ROW()`, which can be cast into your new `test_type`

```
insert into test_table (test_column)
values (
        ARRAY[   
          ROW(ARRAY[(1,'m')::length, (20,'m')::length])::test_type,
          ROW(ARRAY[(3,'m')::length, (40,'m')::length])::test_type
        ]
);
```