# Write insert query with udt array which contains udt array

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I am trying to create the next table structure:

```
create type my_type1 as (val_s text);
create type my_type2 as (val_s text, val_t my_type1[]);
create table my_table(val_t my_type2[]);
```

And I want to write an insert query like this:
`insert into my_table (val_t) values ('{ "text", ''{"text1","text2"}'' }');`

Please, help. I am using PostgreSQL 12

`insert into my_table (val_t) values ('{ "text", ''{"text1","text2"}'' }');`

Comment: Are you getting any error when executing your DDL and INSERT query ?

Comment: Yes, I can not run insert query. It is my main question. I found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/66384769/19593931 . But I want to insert without ARRAY and ROW keywords

Comment: The `insert statement is repeated`. It irritates me this way.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to just have the data inserted as it is you can use the `TEXT` datatype

**Schema (PostgreSQL v12)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    val_t         text
);

insert into my_table (val_t) values ('{ "text", ''{"text1","text2"}'' }');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

| val_t |
| --- |
| { "text", '{"text1","text2"}' } |

---

Comment: Sorry, but I need UDTs